# AsyncTask send bool value to C# WebService

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

I have a problem about sending bool value to webservice.

Here is background code

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                method = new WebServiceGlobalMethod(sendedOrReceived, "Object");

                method.request.addProperty("TC", UserInfo.TRNo);
                method.request.addProperty("IsStudent", UserInfo.IsStudent);

                method.Method();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

I'm sending 2 value; TC is long number, IsStudent is bool. When IsStudent value is true, there is no problem but when IsStudent value is false, my response is null. Normally when I invoke my webservice manuel and I send true or false, I'm getting my results truely. (In my service, my variable is bool.) What do you think about the problem? Why I can't my results from webservice?

Comment: You cannot send bools. Or integers. You can only send text. So make a tekst from it. "true", "false".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
method.request.addProperty("IsStudent", "" + UserInfo.IsStudent);
```

or

```
method.request.addProperty("IsStudent", Boolean.toString( UserInfo.IsStudent ) );
```

Comment: As you're probably already aware, answers are generally much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)